# View contents of file with Content-disposition: attachment using socket

Tags: php, content-disposition, fsockopen

I want to parse the contents of a dynamic .csv file. However, this code (obviously with duff file names, etc.):

```
$socket = fsockopen("www.example.com", 443);
fwrite($socket, "GET /dynamicCsv.csv?param=value HTTP/1.1\r\n");
fwrite($socket, "Host: www.example.com\r\n");
fwrite($socket, "Connection: close\r\n");
fwrite($socket, "\r\n");

while(!feof($socket)) echo fgets($socket);
```

...just downloads the file.

Using openssl at command line I can type the exact same request and get the following response header sent back:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=dynamicCsv.csv
Pragma: public
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Set-Cookie: SESSIONID=ASDFUHN023UIN0F; Path=/; Secure
Content-Type: text/csv;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 04 Feb 2010 16:53:00 GMT
```

To avoid having the file download automatically I have tried to chop off the first character using `substr`, in the hope that maybe the browser sees the response output by `fgets` as a set of headers of the current document. That didn't work. Pursuing the same idea I also tried to insert a bunch of newlines before opening the socket, which didn't work either.

My two questions are:

1. Why on earth does the browser think it should download the file?
2. How can I stop it?

I should mention that I've only used Chrome so far, but I don't see why it would make a difference.

Many thanks,
Andreas

Comment: When your script runs, it doesn't output anything because it gets interrupted with a download file dialog? Is that correct?

Comment: Actually, I think I've come across a rather curious piece of behaviour in Chrome here. What it does is that it only downloads the file that I want to output. If I echo out anything prior to opening the socket and making the request, it is echoed on screen as expected. However, in Firefox, without specifying ssl, only a few non-ascii characters are output, same results when nc'ing on port 80. It seems as though Chrome parses the socket response separately, being intelligent enough to handle two protocols (http and https) on the same document. Might be worthy of a more thorough investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I actually managed to solve it myself. For reference, instead of removing the question I add this response with the fix.

The problem was that in

```
fsockopen("www.example.com", 443);
```

I did not specify to use the ssl protocol. So the fix is to instead type:

```
fsockopen("ssl://www.example.com", 443);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [cURL](http://php.net/curl) or [some](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) [other wrapper](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Client) for it.